# How to use SSHPass with WSL to autostart & login a session

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sshpass, windows-terminal

This might seem a little confusing, but I have a server I want to SSH into but the password is kinda long and complex, I understand for security I shouldn't save my password in plain text but for my convenience, I'm not too worried. Regardless, I'm trying to make it so I can just start up a Linux distro in WSL that automatically connects me to my SSH server and logs in but I'm having trouble. My settings.json block looks kinda like:

```
            {
                "guid": "{46ca431a-3a87-5fb3-83cd-11ececc031d2}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "SSH",
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
                "commandline": "/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host"
            },
```

then when I start that distro I get:

```
[error 0x80070002 when launching `/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host']
```

Is there another way to do this? And yes I have sshpass installed on literally all my distros just to be 100% sure. I googled around for an sshpass Windows version but can't find it. I've also tried just using `sshpass` instead of `/usr/bin/sshpass` but it doesn't work either.

As far as I know `error 0x80070002` is a file not found error, but I don't know where the command isn't being found. Does the `"commandline"` setting get loaded before even the Linux Kernel? Is there a way to launch the command AFTER Linux initializes?

Answer (score 0):

Like the picture below, you should add the fingerprint to the `.ssh/known_hosts` file first.

[image]

Then add sshpass command line to the Window Termial settings.

[image]